# How can I maintain the current selection in a sorted silverlight treeview?

Tags: c#, silverlight, sorting, treeview, collectionviewsource

I have a silverlight 4 `TreeView` control with a hierarchy of data. I want the items in each level to be sorted alphabetically, so I am using a `CollectionViewSource`, but don't actually care how the sorting is accomplished.

The `CollectionViewSource` seems to observe `CollectionChanged` events, so the sorting works fine as items are added and removed.

The `CollectionViewSource` does not observe changes to the property being sorted upon, so when the item's text changes, the sorting is not maintained. Calling `CollectionViewSource.View.Refresh()` re-sorts the list, but discards the selection. How can I keep the `TreeView` selection **without losing and re-setting the selection**?

**Sample Project:**

*Description:*

This project creates a single-level tree of items. Each item is given an item number, and a numeric prefix to make the sorting actually do something interesting. The buttons will add an item, remove the oldest item, and rename the oldest item.

*Building the sample:*

- Create a new silverlight application named "SortTest"
- Add a reference to System.Windows.Controls (for the treeview)
- Update the following files:

*Behavior to note:*

- The current selection is maintained as items are added and removed.
- The current selection is lost when an item is renamed (when `Refresh()` is called from within `OnRenameButtonClick()`).
- If the call to `Refresh()` is removed, the selection is maintained when renaming an item, but the list is not re-sorted to account for the name change.

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="SortTest.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="expandedStyle" TargetType="sdk:TreeViewItem">
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="true" />
        </Style>

        <sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="template">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </sdk:HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Click="OnAddButtonClick">
                <TextBlock Text="Add an item" />
            </Button>
            <Button Click="OnRemoveButtonClick">
                <TextBlock Text="Remove lowest numbered item" />
            </Button>
            <Button Click="OnRenameButtonClick">
                <TextBlock Text="Rename lowest numbered item" />
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>

        <sdk:TreeView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource template}" />

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

namespace SortTest
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        private ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> items = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();
        private CollectionViewSource sortedItems = new CollectionViewSource();
        private int itemNumber = 1;

        public MainPage()
        {
            sortedItems.Source = items;
            sortedItems.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Name", ListSortDirection.Ascending));

            DataContext = this;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public ICollectionView Items { get { return sortedItems.View; } }

        private void OnAddButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ItemViewModel item = new ItemViewModel();
            item.Name = DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString("D3") + " Item #" + itemNumber;
            itemNumber++;
            items.Add(item);
        }

        private void OnRemoveButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (items.Count > 0)
            {
                items.RemoveAt(0);
            }
        }

        private void OnRenameButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (items.Count > 0)
            {
                items[0].Name = DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString("D3") + items[0].Name.Substring(3);
                sortedItems.View.Refresh();
            }
        }
    }

    public class ItemViewModel : DependencyObject
    {
        public static DependencyProperty NameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Name", typeof(string), typeof(ItemViewModel), null);
        public string Name
        {
            get { return GetValue(NameProperty) as string; }
            set { SetValue(NameProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

persist the selected item into the isolatedStorage and reselect it after your treeview is reloaded.